# Почему не работает ограничение диапазона символов {n,m}?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Я ненавижу регулярки и только по этому хочется разобраться во всем.
Вот почему находится **с** тогда и только тогда, когда после идет от трех и более символов **а**.

```
var str = 'caaa';
var re = /c(?=a{3,})/;
```

Но если поставить ограничение на максимум, то выражение уже не работает и **с** выводится если даже будет сто символов **а**.

```
var str = 'caaaaaaaaa';
var re = /c(?=a{3,5})/;
```

Почему так и как сделать, чтобы так не было?

**Добавлено:**

```
var str = '/**a';
var re = /\/\*{1,2}(?=(a{1,2}))/
```

Хочется вот чего... В коде выше, в условии выражения говорится, если звездочек будет меньше одной или больше двух, то результат будет null, так-как выражение не строка не соответствует искомыму шаблону. Но вот почему в этом же коде нет реакции на ограничение символа "а"???

Comment: @vas, caaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa вполне содержит в себе паттерн "`с`, затем от трех до пяти `а`". Остальная часть просто игнорируется. Используйте метасимвол конца строки($), чтобы обозначить явный конец тестируемого паттерном отрезка.

Comment: @eicto, я немного рассширил свои объяснения и сейчас Ваш пример посмотрю.

Comment: @eicto, о да! Можете дать ответ. И объяснить, смысл цифры 5 :) Ведь по сути, её обязанность выполняет слудующее выражение.. А почему 5 не работает там, где это ожидается?

Comment: 5 не нужна  :) скорее для читаемости

Answer (score 4, accepted):

этого хочется ?

```
str.match(/c(?=a{3,5})(?!a{6,})/)
```

почему в вашем примере ограничиваются звездочки а символы "a" не ограничиваются ? потому-что после зведочек есть символ (стоп-символ если угодно) а после "a" нет, используйте negative lookahead как я показал.

5ка тут ничего не делает, но читать с ней удобнее, т.е. тоже самое будет

```
   str.match(/c(?=a{3,})(?!a{6,})/)
    есть "c" ? _| | | |  | | |
есть ли после "c"_| | |  | | |
                "a"_| |  | | |
        3 и более раз_|  | | |
    а нет ли (после "c")_| | |
                       "a"_| |
             6 и более раз ?_|
```

Comment: @eicto, Спасибо! Наконец-то я понял, как это сделать! И про цифру 5 с Вами тоже согласен :) Спасибо!

Comment: не понял задачи сделайте лучше так - список строк, которые должны матчится и список тех, которые не должны. из того что вы написали мне ничего не понятно

    /c(?=ag)(?=ga)(?![ag]{3,})../

?

Comment: Чтобы было предельно понятно, то я хочу комменты из файла парсить. Я бы мог это в самом первом вопросе спросить и наверняка, кто-нибудь бы сделал за меня, но я хочу сам научится. Вот только мое глобальное непонимание регулярных выражений заставляет меня чуть ли не все подряд спрашивать. Хотя доки читаю...  Вот смотрите, комменты начинаются со слеша, после которого идут одна или две звездочки. То есnm мне нужно, чтобы не получилось вот так /*8* и в тот же момент мне нужно, чтобы я контролировал количество звездочек.

Comment: А в моем примере выше g не должна пройти. Я должен быть уверен, что выбрав диапазон из 10 символов "а", он и будет состоять из них и другие символы туда не впишутся.

```var str = 'caga';```

Comment: пока вот так получилось  /c(?=(a{1,2}(?=a$)))(?!a{4,})/  такие сложные и запутывающие выражения обязывают пересмотреть несколько слеующих шагов...

Comment: это какие-то спец коменты ? просто коменты начинаются обычно с двух слэшей и заканчиваются концом строки, либо со `/*` и заканчиваются `*/` и  сколько там между ними звездочек обычно не важно.

Answer (score 4):

намудрили вы че-то. вот:

```
var re = /ca{3,}/;
```

Comment: @mountpoint, получается, что нет возможности на указание-проверки количества символов? Пипа верно, если после "с" идут десять "а", а не более?

Comment: @vas, что за пипа? если нужно жестко ограничить, пишите ca{3,10}

Answer (score 3):

zxcxczcaaaavdsfcxv|caa|sdcasdas|caaaaa|caaaaaaaaaaaaa|caaaaa

---

```
c(?=a{3,5}([^a]+|$))
```

Comment: я бы тогда ?:  сделал `/c(?=a{3,5}(?:[^a]+|$))/`

Comment: Да, согласен, так лучше.

Comment: Объясните на словах, что оно означает, а то я не понимаю, что после закрывающей фигурной скобки происходит. "Си" после которой обязательно идет "а" в количестве от трех до пяти символов. А дальше?

Comment: a{3,5}(?:[^a]+|$) - означает, что после a{3,5} (3-5 "a") будут либо символы, отличные от "a" (1 или более), либо конец строки.
?: - пассивная группа, т. е. не участвует в подстановке.